# @ConfigurationProperties in SpringBootTest have two qualified bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

The SpringBoot version is 2.3.3.RELEASE. And in pom.xml the `spring-boot-configuration-processor` dependency exists.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

I write a class to define some properties:

```
@RefreshScope
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {PatrolProperties.class})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "patrol")
@Configuration
public class PatrolProperties implements Serializable {

  private String baseUri;
  private String sign;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String clientId;
  private String idNo;
  private String apiVer;
  // getter and setter
}
```

in `bootstrap.yml`:

```
patrol:
  baseUri: http://xxx.aaa.com/api
  sign: 111111111111111111111
  username: root
  password: 123456
  clientId: 123456
  idNo: 123456
  apiVer: v1
  updateInterval: 30
```

in PatrialStatusCheckServiceImpl:

```
@Service
@Slf4j

public class PatrolStatusCheckService {

  private final PatrolProperties prop;

  private Map<String, Object> propMap;


  @Autowired
  public PatrolStatusCheckService( PatrolProperties prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
    this.propMap = ObjectToMapUtils.objectToMap(prop);
  }

  /**
   * alias for url1
   *
   * @return signKey
   */
  public String getSignKey() {
    StrSubstitutor sb = new StrSubstitutor(propMap);
    String url1 = sb.replace(PatrolUrlConstant.url1);
    log.info("-----url1:{}", url1);

    String resp = HttpUtil.get(url1);
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(resp)) {
      throw new RuntimeException("exception...");
    }
    JSONObject data = getDataObjFromResp(resp);
    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
      return data.getString("signKey");
    }
    return "";
  }
}
```

in src/main/test/java/patrol/PatrolTest.java:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes= DMSApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Slf4j
public class PatrolTest {

  @Autowired
  private PatrolStatusCheckService patrolStatusCheckService;

  @Test
  public void testUrl1() {
    String signKey = patrolStatusCheckService.getSignKey();
    log.info("url1-signKey:{}", signKey);
    Assert.assertNotEquals("", signKey);
  }
}
```

error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.supconit.patrol.service.impl.PatrolStatusCheckService required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - patrolProperties: defined in BeanDefinition defined in file [D:\supconit\dmszhly\dmszhly_master\target\classes\com\supconit\patrol\properties\PatrolProperties.class]
    - patrol-com.supconit.patrol.properties.PatrolProperties: defined in null
```

Why is there a `patrol-com.supconit.patrol.properties.PatrolProperties: defined in null` bean?

In Idea, when I change the name of the directory where PatrolTest.java stays to `patroltest`, which the full path is `src/main/test/java/patroltest/PatrolTest.java`,`@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "patrol")` turned to `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "patroltet")` the same time.

---

UPDATE:

If I comment `@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {PatrolProperties.class})`, then the application runs. But the debugger doesn't turn into setter methods [image], it turns into PatrolStatusCheckService constructor first with all properties at null! [image]

---

UPDATE:

Removing `@Configuration`, `@RefreshScope` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {PatrolProperties.class})` and then add `@Component` does work!

What is the rationale behind this?

Comment: In your error message is a service named `PatrolStatusCheckServiceImpl` where is the code for it. Note the `Impl` suffix.

Comment: @ValerijDobler Sorry thatI copied the older logs, now with the name `PatrolStatusCheckService`, the same problem exists.

Comment: Try removing the `@Configuration` annotation from the `PatrolProperties` class.

Comment: @ValerijDobler Removing both `@Configuration` and `@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {PatrolProperties.class})` and then add `@Component` does work!

Comment: I would say that removing `@RefreshScope` and leaving empty `@EnableConfigurationproperties` would do the trick